''plot.phylo'' visualizes the phylogenetic tree, but eventually some phylum colors are overwritten
I'm having trouble visualizing an evolutionary tree.
In my evolutionary tree file, there are a total of 25 phylum, I filtered out 12 phylum, and the rest were classified as Others. Now I want to visualize the evolutionary tree containing 12 phylum. I assigned an exclusive color to each of these 12 phylum, but in the end only the colors of 8 phylum are displayed. The final troubleshooting found that the color abundance of Acidobacteria in the edge_color file was abnormal. Acidobacteria occupied 13,188 out of a total of 22,091 branches. How should I deal with this?
By checking
for (phylum_ in phylums){
      Ancestor <- getMRCA(otu_tree,OTU_taxa %>% filter(Phylum==phylum_) %>% pull(OTUID))
      Children <- getDescendants(otu_tree,node=Ancestor)
      #edge_color[edge_color$V1 %in% Children, 'color'] <- phylum_colors[phylum_]
      edge_color[edge_color$V2 %in% Children, 'color'] <- phylum_color[phylum_]
     }

The code and results of this step. In the output result file: edge_color, it was found that Acidobacteria covered the colors of other phylum. How can I make all 12 phylum colors fully displayed? Below is my complete code
otutab <- read.csv("otutab_info.csv")
otu_tree <- ape::read.tree("otus.nwk")
OTU_taxa <- otutab[,c(1,230)]
phylums <- OTU_taxa %>% pull(Phylum) %>% unique()
phylums
[1] "Proteobacteria"              "Actinobacteria"              "Firmicutes"                  "Unassigned"                  "Deinococcus-Thermus"        
 [6] "Bacteroidetes"               "Gemmatimonadetes"            "Acidobacteria"               "Verrucomicrobia"             "Chloroflexi"                
[11] "Planctomycetes"              "Nitrospirae"                 "Ignavibacteriae"             "Latescibacteria"             "Candidatus_Saccharibacteria"
[16] "Spirochaetes"                "Armatimonadetes"             "Aminicenantes"               "Fibrobacteres"               "BRC1"                       
[21] "Chlamydiae"                  "Euryarchaeota"               "Fusobacteria"                "Parcubacteria"               "Hydrogenedentes"    

OTU_taxa %>% 
group_by(Phylum) %>% 
summarise(n()) %>%
print(n=Inf)
# A tibble: 25 × 2
   Phylum                      `n()`
   <chr>                       <int>
 1 Acidobacteria                1054
 2 Actinobacteria               2835
 3 Aminicenantes                   4
 4 Armatimonadetes                15
 5 BRC1                            3
 6 Bacteroidetes                 963
 7 Candidatus_Saccharibacteria    19
 8 Chlamydiae                      2
 9 Chloroflexi                   138
10 Deinococcus-Thermus            79
11 Euryarchaeota                   1
12 Fibrobacteres                   2
13 Firmicutes                    569
14 Fusobacteria                    1
15 Gemmatimonadetes              267
16 Hydrogenedentes                 1
17 Ignavibacteriae                10
18 Latescibacteria                18
19 Nitrospirae                    38
20 Parcubacteria                   1
21 Planctomycetes                  8
22 Proteobacteria               3734
23 Spirochaetes                    5
24 Unassigned                   1201
25 Verrucomicrobia                79

a <- c("Aminicenantes","BRC1","Chlamydiae","Euryarchaeota","Fibrobacteres","Fusobacteria","Hydrogenedentes",
       "Parcubacteria","Spirochaetes","Armatimonadetes", "Candidatus_Saccharibacteria",
        "Ignavibacteriae", "Latescibacteria")  
OTU_taxa[OTU_taxa$Phylum %in% a, 'Phylum'] <- "Others"
phylum_color <- tribble(
  ~phylum, ~color,
  "Acidobacteria","#00C9A7",
  "Gemmatimonadetes","#007554",
  "Deinococcus-Thermus","#ab5f1f",
  "Firmicutes","#FF8066",
  "Proteobacteria", "#B39CD0",
  "Actinobacteria", "#54c3ff",
  "Unassigned", "#75b831",
  "Bacteroidetes","#b04380",
  "Chloroflexi","#e69f00",
  "Nitrospirae","#114662",
  "Planctomycetes","#D5CABD",
  "Verrucomicrobia","#845EC2",
  "Others", "#a6a6a6"
) %>%
  deframe()


edge_color <- as.data.frame(otu_tree$edge)
edge_color$color <- '#a6a6a6'
phylums <- OTU_taxa %>% pull(Phylum) %>% unique()
phylums
 [1] "Proteobacteria"      "Actinobacteria"      "Firmicutes"          "Unassigned"          "Deinococcus-Thermus" "Bacteroidetes"       "Gemmatimonadetes"   
 [8] "Acidobacteria"       "Verrucomicrobia"     "Chloroflexi"         "Planctomycetes"      "Nitrospirae"         "Others" 

phylums <- phylums[-13] # Others at position 13
for (phylum_ in phylums){
     Ancestor <- getMRCA(otu_tree,OTU_taxa %>% filter(Phylum==phylum_) %>% pull(OTUID))
     Children <- getDescendants(otu_tree,node=Ancestor)
     #edge_color[edge_color$V1 %in% Children, 'color'] <- phylum_colors[phylum_]
     edge_color[edge_color$V2 %in% Children, 'color'] <- phylum_color[phylum_]
    }


plot.phylo(otu_tree, type = "radial", show.tip.label=F, x.lim = c(-1,1), y.lim=c(-1,1), edge.color = edge_color$color)

